# Should I learn javascript again after learning Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I learned javascript 6 months ago and made many projects to practice it. After that I stop learning and revising javascript as I learned MERN stack. But now I am not feeling confident about my javascript skills.

Should I revise it again or should I continue to learn and practice Reactjs?

Comment: Without Javascript skill you cannot learn 3 of MERN. Javascript is important for Express, React and Node.

Comment: You don't just "learn" JavaScript in six months. You can certainly learn the basics, but there's so much to the language that learning and understanding it is a continual process, IMO. Having a strong background in JS will help you understand React and NodeJS better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn Javascript again if you want to be a good developer. There are 2 kinds of developers out there:

1. How group - This kind of developer knows how to do things. They know the syntaxes. Then when working on large applications they can't debug things well. They're just copy, & paste experts.
2. Why group - These people not only know how to do it but also know why the code doing this way. For example, they don't only know what is lexical scoping, but also how scoping works under the hood using a closure.

End of the day, I wanna say, if you only know how to write Javascript, then Javascript seems like a magical thing for you. But if you also know how Javascript works under the hood, you will be a magical thing to Javascript.